# PDFDecoder API of JPedal - Does it read flattenned pages in a PDF?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpedal

I have a huge PDF which holds very few pages as images. When i use the PDFDecoder API of Java, does it reads these flattenned [image] pages of the PDF also perfectly?

I have attached the code snippet i use for extracting the page data along with this question FYR.

// Decode the page

decodePdf.decodePage(page);

// Create the grouping object to apply grouping to the data

PdfGroupingAlgorithms currentGrouping = decodePdf.getGroupingObject();

```
            // Bounding box for the whole page
            PdfPageData currentPageData = decodePdf.getPdfPageData();
```

Answer (score 0):

JPedal will read flattened pages.

There is a support forum/help section at http://www.jpedal.org/support.php and their blog has a lot of general articles related to PDF and Java (http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/).